# How to save a BLOB to a readable file like .txt or .jpg?

Tags: php, sqlite

having a big trouble trying to make this blob saved to a file and load it as an image.

Using SQLite Manager (Firefox Add-on) I was able to "Save As" a file with the content of my image BLOB. The result is a strange (for me) code.

Since I can´t post the "source of the file", I'm attaching one png with the example.

[image: example]

In my Mac, the saved file has no extention but I can view the image it produces as thumbnail.

So I'm trying to achieve the same result saving one file, but all I get is a 16 bytes document I can't read...

```
$pic = fopen('pics/thumbnails/pic_'.$id.'', 'w');
fwrite($pic, base64_encode($theFile));
fclose($pic);
```

*** EDIT ***

```
$theFile = shell_exec("sqlite3 AddressBookImages.sqlitedb 'select data from ABThumbnailImage where record_id = ".$id."'");
if($theFile != '') {
    file_put_contents('pics/thumbnails/pic_'.$id.'.jpg', $theFile);
}
```

Comment: `base64_encode` is a definite error here. But what is `$theFile`???

Comment: oh, $theFile is the result of the sqlite query $theFile = $row['data'];

Comment: You should try simply `file_put_contents('pics/thumbnails/pic_'.$id, $theFile)`. If that doesn't work, then there's something wrong involving the database.

Comment: I really really hate to point out the obvious, but don't base64_encode it, and save it with an extension.

Comment: tried with Jon suggestion, no luck, it saves the file, but I can't read it.

Comment: just edited the question with the sqlite command. I assume the database is ok, since the SQLite manager can read and save the contents of database.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use (b for binary)

```
$pic = fopen('pics/thumbnails/pic_'.$id.'', 'wb');
```

Comment: i did try with the wb, no luck either

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution to this, but its very slow, I'm posting a new question to ask help for improve this.

```
$sql2 = shell_exec("sqlite3 ".$endereco_iphone."".$db_pics." 'select hex(data) from ABThumbnailImage where record_id = ".$id."'");
//
if($sql2 !='' && $sql2 != 'NULL') {
    $img = '';
    foreach(explode("\n",trim(chunk_split($sql2,2))) as $h) {
        $img .= chr(hexdec($h));
    }
    if(file_put_contents('pics/thumbnails/pic_'.$id.'.jpg', $img)) {
        $cnt .= "<img class='pics' src='pics/thumbnails/pic_".$id.".jpg' width='30px' height='30px'></img>";
    }
} else {
    $cnt .= "<div class='pics'></div>";
}
```